# How to limit user action in java menu?

Tags: java

I am trying to create a menu option for a user to interact with cat by entering a number. But I am getting an red error under option ==1. Also I would like to limit user so that it cannot overfeed cat by making it only if health level is less than 60 they can feed it. I would also like to make an option for user to exit program.

```
String options;
System.out.println("pick an option ");
System.out.println(" Option 1 feed cat ");
System.out.println(" Option 2 play with cat");
System.out.println(" Option 3 give cat bath");
option = input.nextLine();
if(option == 1) {
    food += 10;
    happiness -= 15;
} else if (option == 2) {
    happiness += 12;
    health += 25;
}
```

Comment: `options` is a String and can not be directly compared with the integer value．Consider comparing to the Strings value `"1"` using the `equals` method

Comment: You are supposed to use `While` loop to make user continuously interact with the cat until the exit option is selected.

Answer (score 0):

As Scary Wombat said, you are comparing a `String` to an `int`. There are two Solutions to this:

1. Compare to a `String` instead of an `int` (Note that you have to use `equals` here instead of `==`)

```
if(option.equals("1")) {
    //...
} else if (option.equals("2")) {
    //...
}
```

2. Assuming `input` is of type `Scanner`, read an `int` instead of a `String` (Note that this will throw an Exception if the user Inputs something that is not an integer)

```
option = input.nextInt();
```